# Using Autowired bean inside Preauthorize expression in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have the following class for a resource in my Spring Application

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/whatever")
public class SomeResource {

@Autowired
private CoolService coolService;

@RequestMapping(
            path = "",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @PreAuthorize("hasPerm(@coolService.resolve(#attribute))")
    public void resource(@PathVariable("attribute") int attribute) {
        ...
    }
```

And I want to call the bean implementing `CoolService` that has been autowired by the Spring context, because for `CoolService` I have two beans that get activated depending on the profile at startup.

```
public interface CoolService {

    resolve(int attribute);
}
```

```
@Service
@Profile("super")
public interface SuperCoolService implements CoolService {

    public Object resolve(int attribute){...}
}
```

```
@Service
@Profile("ultra")
public interface UltraCoolService implements CoolService {

    public Object resolve(int attribute){...}
}
```

However it seems that Spring does not know which bean to use because there is no single bean just named `CoolService`, and inside the `Preauthorize` I can't write `@superCoolService` or `@ultraCoolService` because it is profile-dependant.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Note that `@coolService` refers to the _bean name in the Spring context_ and not the field on the service class. It might be best to [implement a custom expression object](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression#customExpression).

Comment: Yeah I imagined that by using `@coolService` I was referring to that but I assumed that Spring could resolve the bean if no bean with that explicit name was found. Or at least that there was another way to refer to an autowired bean? But I couldn't find anything...

Comment: You can use the permission evaluator along with Custom Expression to define the custom authorization. Look through it :  https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression

Comment: Specify the name (the same!) in the `@Service` annotation. Only 1 of them should be active in a certain profile.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes I know I can do that, I know that when I want `SuperCoolService` I can put `@superCoolService` with `@Service("superCoolService")` and make it work, but SuperCoolService and UltraCoolService are profile dependant. If now I want SuperCoolService but in the future I want UltraCoolService, I don't want to go down into the code and change the `@superCoolService` in the `PreAuthorize` to `@ultraCoolService`, I want to just change the profile and get the correct service called in the `Preauthorize`

Comment: Read my comment... Add `@Service("coolService")` to your implementations (that is what I suggested).

Comment: Aaaah okay now i understand you. Yes I think this might be the more simple solution,  thanks! Put it as a solution, i will mark it as the solution as soon as i can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to define 2 bean implement same interface, then you can user annotation @Qualifier.
For example:

```
@Service
@Qualifier("service1")
public interface SuperCoolService implements CoolService {

    public Object resolve(int attribute){...}
}

@Service
@Qualifier("service1")
public interface UltraCoolService implements CoolService {

    public Object resolve(int attribute){...}
}
```

Comment: But that does not solve my issue, because then in the `PreAuthorize` statement I have to put `@service1` or `@service2` depending on which I want to use (that means changing the code, building and recompiling everything), and I want them to be solved by Spring depending on the profile.